# Query SQL by using python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I try to query SQL by using python but it returns question mark.

This is my code.

```
import cx_Oracle
import importlib

class CustomDatabase(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes _dbconnection to None.
        """
        self._dbconnection = None
        self.db_api_module_name = None

    def GetDataFromDatabaseByRow(self, db_connect_string, selectStatement, row):
        db_api_2 = importlib.import_module("cx_Oracle")
        db_connect_string = 'db_api_2.connect(%s)' % db_connect_string
        self.db_api_module_name = "cx_Oracle"
        self._dbconnection = eval(db_connect_string)
        row = int(row)
        cur = None
        try:
            cur = self._dbconnection.cursor()
            cur.execute(selectStatement)
            res = cur.fetchone()
            i = 0
            while (i < row):
                if cur.rowcount == row:
                    data = res
                res = cur.fetchone()
                i = i + 1
                if i == row:
                    for x in data:  
                        result=x
            #return result.decode('iso-8859-11')
            return result
        finally :
            if cur :
                self._dbconnection.rollback()

Obj=CustomDatabase()
A=Obj.GetDataFromDatabaseByRow("'BELL', 'BELL#', '192.168.1.10:110/BELL'","select book_name from book where id='100'",1)
print A
```

This is actual result.

```
OOP ???????
```

This is value in DB.

```
OOP แม่เจ้า
```

I want expected value to be `OOP แม่เจ้า` (Thai language).

Could you please help me?

Comment: what if you modify this one `"select book_name from book where id='100'"` into `"select book_name from book where id=100"`?

Comment: You need to fix your encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Oracle `NLS_LANG` environment variable before starting Python, for example

```
export NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
```

(yes, there is a full stop after the '=').

Oracle documentation on globalization is [Database Globalization Support Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/NLSPG/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.htm#NLSPG190)

[Updated] @anthony-tuininga [pointed out](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/36#issuecomment-307204351) that you can simply do:

`import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString, encoding = "UTF-8", nencoding = "UTF-8")`

There is no need for `NLS_LANG` in this example.  The `nencoding` option can be omitted if you are not using NCHAR data.